# Headers while running EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, python-requests

I am attempting to run my code on a aws ec2(ubuntu) instance. The codes work perfectly fine on my local but doesnt seem to be able to connect to website inside server.

Im assuming it has to do something with the headers. I have installed *firefox* and *chrome* on the server but doesnt seem to do anything.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem would be appreciated.

```
import requests 

HEADERS = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'}
# Making a get request 
response = requests.get("https://us.louisvuitton.com/eng-us/products/pocket-organizer-monogram-other-nvprod2380073v", headers=HEADERS) #hangs here, cant make request in server
# print response 
print(response.status_code)
```

Output:

Doesn't give me one, just stays blank until I KeyboardInterrupt.

Comment: Installing browsers won't have any effect whatsoever on your headers, and that's probably not the problem anyway. It's more likely that the site rejects requests from AWS IP ranges.

Comment: Can your EC2 connect outbound to any host?

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Yes, I can reach outbound others hosts.

Comment: This makes me think they're likely blocking the request then? If you've been tasked by the receiver to do this you would need to request with them to whitelist